# Hibernate: Can I get an example on how to relate these tables?

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

I have four tables. Three of them are tables with one key and they relate to each other through the fourth table.

`Movie.id`, `Rater.id`, and `Rating.id` are all foreign keys in table `MRR`.

If it matters, I designated combinations of the `Rater` and `Movie` FKs as unique.

I know there are two ways that I can accomplish this:

1. Using HQL
2. Using Restrictions

I am using Spring. Those are the two I know of. Could someone offer a simple example how to select all the comments from a certain `Rater.id`?

Comment: You don't show the structure of the tables. You don't show what you tried to map them as entities. And there is no question in your post. There are two ways to accomplish *what*? And what does Spring have to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess by "all comments" you mean all ratings. Also assume that MRR is some kind of connector entity that connects ratings, raters and movies. In that case:

```
SELECT mrr.rating FROM MRR mrr WHERE mrr.rater.id=:raterId
```

Comment: This gives a good enough idea. Thanks despite the lack of info.